# Rails Categories dropdown shows an array at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a category menu on my app. I use the below code in my view to get unique categories to display.

```
<%= Listing.uniq.pluck(:category).each do |category| %>
   <%= link_to category, category_path(category: category) %>
<% end %>
```

If you look at the demo at [mktdemo.herokuapp.com](http://mktdemo.herokuapp.com) and click on the category dropdown in the navbar, you'll see the categories displayed. However, at the end, I get an array of all categories. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace the first `<%=` with a `<%-`:

```
<%- Listing.uniq.pluck(:category).each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category, category_path(category: category) %>
<% end %>
```

`<%=` causes the output to be printed, which in your case is an array.

Comment: wow, that was quick. thanks!

Comment: I can't remember how often I've made this mistake myself ;) Glad I could help.